# If I have an image 50dp wide/tall in xhdpi, what size do I make for mdpi?

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview, android-image, android-resolution

I am working with a graphic designer at the moment who is trying to verify what sizes images I am currently using in my app so he can create new images in the right size for all resolution modes (designing the image at the smallest size and then scaling it for the other modes).

In my app, I am emulating a device that is `720 x 1280: xhdpi`, and on this device, an ImageView is set to size `50dp x 50 dp`.

Is it correct to say `50 dp xhdpi -> 25 dp mdpi? 100px? Or 50px?` What exactly? What is the correct size that we should be making for the smallest size?

Answer (score 1):

According to `Android Documentation`.

From a base image size, there is a `3:4:6:8:12:16` scaling ratio in drawable size by DPI.

```
LDPI - 0.75x
MDPI - Original size // means 1.0x here 
HDPI - 1.5x
XHDPI - 2.0x
XXHDPI - 3x
XXXHDPI - 4.0x
```

According to the upper difference you can calculate the ImageSize resoultion.

## Update :

you have create different size of Image like `HDPI`, `MDPI`, `XHDPI`. but that is not mean that you can set  `ImageView` `Height` and `Width` according to it's `Drawable`.

## Example :

let's some device have small screenSize but it is high density support so you have to set high resolution density Image but the Size of the `ImageView` you have create small in that case.

Comment: I know the ratios -- I am trying to use that information to address the question at hand because I am not sure I am applying them correctly

Comment: @user7309495 No you can not set `ImageView` size according to that diffrence.Becuase some device has size small but the Image support is high that's means you can use more size for that Device.

Comment: @user7309495 Now I think you get it.

Comment: What I mean is, if I am using 50dp in xhdpi, does this mean 25dp mdpi?

Comment: @user7309495 no width is not depand on `drawable` size.

Comment: If I am using 50dp in xhdpi, does this mean I need to design a 50x50 px image for mdpi, 75x75 px image for hdpi, 100x100 px image for xhdpi?

Comment: @user7309495 no you have to set `width` and `height` according to `device size`. Not `Image size`.

Comment: I am so confused now. In my app, I set my ImageView to 50dp by 50dp. My device is xhdpi. What does this tell me?

Comment: So is it true that as I move to higher screen res, my assets need to increase in dp? (and likewise lower dp for lower screen res)?